# Is $GL_{n}^{+}(\mathbb R)$ a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-groups

> Is $GL_{n}^{+}(\mathbb R)$ a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$?

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\5 & 7\end{bmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\det(A) = 1$ and $\det(B)=1$.

$AB=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\5 & 7\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 7\\5 & 12\end{bmatrix}$.

$BA=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\5 & 7\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}8 & 5\\5 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Since $AB \ne BA$, $GL_{n}^{+}(\mathbb R)$ is not a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: $AB\neq BA$ has nothing to do with subgroup. Then $GL_n$ would not be a group either. By the way, how do you define $GL_n^+(K)$ ?

Comment: Why are you checking whether the matrices commute? What you need to check is whether their product (in either order) is in the given subset.

Comment: Thanks for stating the fact that $GL^{+}_n(\mathbb{R})$ isn't commutative. What can we do about it?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

To check whether $GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, prove the following:

1. $I \in GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$
2. $A,B \in GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R}) \implies AB^{-1} \in GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Right, via the one step subtest.